# Coldfusion include template dropdown choosing selected value

Tags: coldfusion

I am creating a drop down and am trying to make it automatically have "FL" selected. For some reason its just starting with the first state "AL" in the array. Can someone please tell me where I may be going wrong?

**HTML**

```
<cfinclude template="dlstates.cfm">
```

**dlstates.cfm**

```
<cfset values = "AL,AK,AZ,AR,CA,CO,CT,DE,DC,FL,GA,HI,ID,IL,IN,IA,KS,KY,LA,ME,MD,MA,MI,MN,MS,MO,MT,NE,NV,NH,NJ,NM,NY,NC,ND,OH,OK,OR,PA,RI,SC,SD,TN,TX,UT,VT,VA,WA,WV,WI,WY">
<cfset text = "AL,AK,AZ,AR,CA,CO,CT,DE,DC,FL,GA,HI,ID,IL,IN,IA,KS,KY,LA,ME,MD,MA,MI,MN,MS,MO,MT,NE,NV,NH,NJ,NM,NY,NC,ND,OH,OK,OR,PA,RI,SC,SD,TN,TX,UT,VT,VA,WA,WV,WI,WY">

<cfoutput><select name="dlstate_#Add#" id="dlstate_#Add#" required selected="FL"></cfoutput>
    <cfloop index="x" from="1" to="#listLen(values)#">
        <cfset value = listGetAt(values, x)>
        <cfset label = listGetAt(text, x)>
        <cfoutput>

        <option value="#value#" <cfif isDefined("form.dlstate_#Add#") and form["dlstate_#Add#"] eq value> selected</cfif>>#label#</option> 
        </cfoutput>
    </cfloop>
</select>
```

Comment: im going to go with no lol I have just been trying everything :(

Comment: You need to set a default value for your form field to FL otherwise it'll never get inside your if statement.

Comment: like @MattBusche says, if form.dlstate_#Add# isn't defined, it'll never gets into the cfif to select the option. you could either set a default to form.dlstate_#Add# if it doesn't exist, or change your cfif to have a cfelse it doesn't exist, and the option value is fl, set it to selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `selected` attribute in your `<select>` won't do anything, it is not one of that element's attributes.

In order to have the state of Florida (`FL`) selected, you could add the following near the top of your page (but after the value of `Add` has been set!):

```
<cfparam name="form.dlstate_#Add#" default="FL" />
```

By the way, I would recommend that you stay away from `isDefined()` and use `structKeyExists()` instead. The latter is more efficient:

```
isDefined("form.dlstate_#Add#") ==> structKeyExists(form, "dlstate_#Add#")
```